# Does not receive sms using SmsManager Android Studio

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am  trying to send a message to my phone number whenever i click button in my apps. The apps say "message successfully send" but i did not get any sms. I am not sure whether its my phone number format or my smsmanager function is not correct. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciate. Thank you.

```
public void sendSmsByManager() {
    try {
        // Get the default instance of the SmsManager
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        PendingIntent sentPI;
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

        sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);


        //phone number format is Malaysia +60134567891
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber.getText().toString(), 
                null,  
                smsBody.getText().toString(), 
                sentPI,
                null);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your sms has successfully sent!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your sms has failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the Device Android version?

Comment: Have you added  sms permission in your manifest.If not,please add it.                                                        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

Comment: My device android version 4.4.4 is and yes i already do the SEND_SMS permission.